# Would there be a flame front in this case of combustion

Tags: mechanical-engineering, compressed-air, combustion, fuel

Suppose a piston enclosing an amount of air-fuel mixture and then this piston compresses the mixture to the point of auto ignition, if every part of the mixture ignite simultaneously is it safe to say that there isn't a flame front because it can't move because there is no longer a combustible mixture to move through ?

If there is a flame front are they multiple flame fronts ?

Also if my reasoning is correct does that type of combustion have a name ?

Edit: there is a type of ignition that works this way and it's the HCCI (homogeneous charge compression ignition) but still my question applies does a flame front exist in this case

Comment: Are you assuming that all points of the fluid are at the same temperature?

Comment: @SolarMike Yes,so that every part of the mixture ignite simultaneously